# Nginx GKE ingress allow session affinity

Tags: nginx, cookies, proxy, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I'm deploying an nginx ingress on GKE 1.19.7-gke.1302, and nginx ingress deployed by nginx-ingress-0.8.0 helm chart,and I'm trying to get session affinity work. It works on a managed "gce" ingress and I'm getting the "GCLB" cookie, but not on nginx ingress. These are my configurations:

**nginx-ingress.yaml**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-nginx-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # gke static ip address name
    #kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: my-proxy
    # make ssl connection to the backends (deprecated)
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"
    # don't use http
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
    # enable backend redirections
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    # this is deprecated
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      rewrite ^/kibana/(.*)$ /$2 break;
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root: /
    # enable stickiness
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: cookie
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity-mode: persistent
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: OAUTH
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: "172800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "172800"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-staging
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: my-tls
    hosts: 
    - "test.com"
  rules:
    - host: "test.com"
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: my-nodeport
            servicePort: 80
```

**my-nodeport**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"ports": {"80":"my-backendconfig"}}'
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'
    ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: cookie
  name: my-nodeport
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: my
  sessionAffinity: ClientIP
  sessionAffinityConfig:
    clientIP:
      timeoutSeconds: 10800
  type: NodePort
```

**my-backendconfig**

```
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  annotations:
  name: my-backendconfig
  namespace: default
spec:
  sessionAffinity:
    affinityCookieTtlSec: 6000
    affinityType: GENERATED_COOKIE
```

My goal is to serve an HTTPS proxy with session affinity and then pass an header to my application, which is not possible with the built in GCE ingress, so I'm trying to do it with nginss ingress. **Other solutions instead of nginx ingress will solve my problem too!**

Comment: Could you please ellaborate about your requirement? Are you seeing any error? Have you checked [this](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/affinity/cookie/)?

Comment: The requirement is sticky sessions on gke nginx ingress, exactly what's in the link you sent, but it's not working for me for some reason. I even used their example and it didn't work also. Perhaps because of the google kubernetes system?

Comment: It has solved by upgrading the helm nginx ingress. Thanks!